# Split sentence(HTML code) into words by spaces and brackets

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-split

For example I want to split following HTML code:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Output should be seperated by spaces as well as angle brackets

```
Array(
[0] => <
[1] => a
[2] => href="http://www.google.com"
[4] => >
[5] => Google
[6] => <
[7] => /a
[8] => >
```

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: I used this to seperate by spaces
$split = preg_split("/[^\w]*([\s]+[^\w]*|$)/", $sentence, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of what you are trying to achieve, but for your example, you can use the option `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` that includes captured parts of the delimiter in the result:

```
$result = preg_split('/([<>])| /', $txt, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: @Rishi: and what is the goal of this?

Comment: Developing a script to identify html page type. (ie advertisement page or not)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> '<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>'
    .match(/(<)(\w+)\s+(href=\"[\w\/:.]+\")\s*(>)(.*)?(<)(\/\w)(>)/)

 ["<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>" 
  ,"<", "a", "href="http://www.google.com"", ">", "Google", "<", "/a", ">"]
```